# Time series with categories manipulation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series

I have a table with three columns: `Date`, `Individual` and `Category`. 
I do not know how many individuals there are.
I also do not know how many categories there are in total. 
Here is a toy example that I manually created with two individuals and three categories:

```
Date         Indiv Cat
3/7/2019    IndivA  1
4/7/2019    IndivA  1
5/7/2019    IndivA  1
6/7/2019    IndivA  1
7/7/2019    IndivA  2
8/7/2019    IndivA  2
9/7/2019    IndivA  3
10/7/2019   IndivA  2
11/7/2019   IndivA  2
3/7/2019    IndivB  1
4/7/2019    IndivB  1
5/7/2019    IndivB  1
6/7/2019    IndivB  2
7/7/2019    IndivB  2
8/7/2019    IndivB  3
9/7/2019    IndivB  3
10/7/2019   IndivB  3
11/7/2019   IndivB  2
```

Here is the expected out:

```
Date    Cat1  Cat2  Cat3
3/7/2019    2   0   0
4/7/2019    2   0   0
5/7/2019    2   0   0
6/7/2019    1   1   0
7/7/2019    0   2   0
8/7/2019    0   1   1
9/7/2019    0   0   2
10/7/2019   0   1   1
11/7/2019   0   1   0
```

The number of column will vary depending on the number of category. 
The number of rows will vary depending on the date length.

Is there an way to transform the initial table to yield the result that I created manually please ?

Comment: Try: `df %>% group_by(Date, Cat) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% spread(Cat, n)`

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much! I guess it is the same answer? it works well!

Comment: I suggested an attempt. Cett, who answered after my comment, wrote down a different approach., but then edited to what it's pretty much the code in my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the `dplyr` package and aggregate by date and `Cat`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Cat = paste0("Cat", Cat)) %>%
  group_by(Date, Cat) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  spread(Cat, n)
```